# How to get the scope when looping through an array in EXTJS

Tags: javascript, extjs

I have an array that I need to iterate through to get a value.

```
    someFunc: function(item) {
          var array = Ext.select(".item").elements;
          var elements;
          var itemId = item.id;
          Ext.each(array, function(ob){
            if (ob.id === itemId) {

              elements = ob.getElementsByTagName("input");
              Ext.each(elements, function(att){
                if (att.getAttribute("name") === "filter") {
                  console.log(att); 
                 this.callFunction();
    // here I want to call a function to do some stuff
    // but `"this"` here refers to input element
   //I should be able to call the function outside the someFunc, but I'm loosing scope
                    }

              });
            }


            });
        },

callFunctionL function() {

}
```

How to maintain the scope while iterating through arrays of array?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are 2 ways:

a) Pass the `scope` parameter to each:

```
Ext.each(o, function() {
    console.log(this);
}, this);
```

b) Capture the scope in a closure:

```
var self = this;
Ext.each(o, function() {
    console.log(self);
});
```